# How to hide multiple divs in a single line of code?

Tags: jquery, html, hide

```
function switch01(){
  $("#contact").hide();
  $("#about").hide();
  $("#mail").hide();
};
```

This works, but I want all the three lines write in a single one.
I tried with `+` and `,` - without result.
In fact I have five divs to hide.

Comment: Can you post your attempt with `,`?

Comment: Most people would add a common class.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See this : http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

```
$("#contact,#about,#mail").hide();
```

should work

Comment: Of, course, I just must wait 10 minutes. It's not possible earlier.

Comment: Good answer as using the Id's should give best performance, but depending on circumstances, you might also consider giving all the relevant divs a common class, and using the class for the selector.

Answer (score 5):

You can comma seperate your answer like this

```
$("#contact, #about, #mail").hide();
```

Example is here

http://jsfiddle.net/c4swG/

I would normally use a class for this however such as hidden

```
<div id="contact" class="hidden">contact</div>
<div id="about" class="hidden">about</div>
<div id="mail" class="hidden">mail</div>

$(".hidden").hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fBucw/